# Change app.config connection string depending on PC

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, linq, app-config

I'm doing a c# course at university, and now I'm beginning linQ to xml, linQ to Sql-Server, etc.
I work with the example projects in two PCs (university PC and office PC)
Is there an easy way to change connection string (from app.config) at runtime, or designtime (using a constant in main.cs) so I can use a connection string at university, and a connection string at the office easily?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="Home"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Work" connectionString="..."/>
    <add name="Home" connectionString="..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and, later:

```
string environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[environment].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: That's very similar to how I do it, but I grab the computer name and based off that determine if its DEV,STAGE,PROD,QA etc..  same thing basically.

Comment: Actually, I comment out lines I don't want; of course, production configurations doesn't exist on development environment

Comment: For code to compile, I had to move <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="Home"/>
  </appSettings> below </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="HomeEnvironment"
             connectionString="Data Source=**HOME-COMPUTER**\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=**HomeDatabase**;Integrated Security=True;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="WorkEnvironment"
             connectionString="DataSource=**WORK-COMPUTER**\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=**WorkDatabase**;Integrated Security=True;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and use it like this:

```
var environment = Environment.MachineName == "HOME-COMPUTER" ? "HomeEnvironment" : "WorkEnvironment";
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[environment].ConnectionString;
var dbContext = new **Databasename**ContextDataContext(connectionString);
```

**Bold** strings should be customised as required